# 'merge' error with check_box field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, checkbox

In my Rails app, I need to show user email id's with checkboxes in a form to allocate users to a particular project. I have an array object `@programmers` and each row in the object contains email id's which I need to show inside the form with checkboxes.

My partial view containing form is:

**_allocate_programmer.html.erb**

```
<h1> Allocate programmers </h1>(Please check the programmers that you want to add)<br />

<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
    <% if @project.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <% unless @programmers.nil? %>
        <% @programmers.each do |programmer| %>
            <%= f.check_box :programmer, programmer.email %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

My **routes.rb** has:

match 'projects/:id/allocate_programmers' => 'projects#allocate'

My **projects_controller.rb** has the following code:

```
  def allocate
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @programmers = User.where(:role => 'programmer')
    render "_allocate_programmer"
  end
```

I am getting following error in the view

```
NoMethodError in Projects#allocate

Showing /home/local/Rajesh/ticket_system/app/views/projects/_allocate_programmer.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method 'merge' for "test@gmail.com":String
```

I think its an issue with checkbox hash. Please help.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :token_authenticatable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, :through => :assignments
  has_many :tickets

  ROLES = ['admin', 'network/system admin', 'manager', 'programmer']

  def role?(base_role)
    ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
  end

end
```

**Project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_name, :description, :duration_from, :duration_upto, :user_id
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments

  validates :project_name, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :duration_from, :presence => true
  validates :duration_upto, :presence => true
  #validates :user_id, :presence => true //this gives error
end
```

**Assignment.rb**

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :project_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Please check. I have updated the question with 3 models.

Comment: Have you adequately set the HABTM relationship between `Project` and `Programmer`?

Comment: No. I have only set HM relationship. and connecting Project and Programmer through another model called assignments because a project can have multiple programmers and vice versa.

Comment: you mean, `has_many :programmers, :through => :assignments`?

Comment: yes. ofcourse and vice versa

Comment: Precisely, that is a _wrong_ way of using checkboxes in association. You are generating checkboxes in an iteration, and using `:programmer` as if it is a attribute of `Project` model. This action will take you to `update` action which doesn't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that you have set up your associations correctly.

```
<% @programmers.each do |programmer| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "project[programmer_ids][]", programmer.id, @project.programmers.include?(programmer) %>
  <%= programmer.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how do I update the project_id and corresponding programmer_id to assignments table?

Comment: That's why I was talking about [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) earlier, Rajesh. You have to set correct `has_many` and `has_many :through` associations between Project, Assignment and Programmer. Once done, above will work just fine.

Comment: I have set has_many :through and has_many associations correctly. But the line @project.programmers throwing error. 

undefined method `programmers' for #<Project:0xb6c2dfc4>

Comment: Erm, there's no reason why that won't work then. Please update the question above with the model declaration of `Programmer`, `Assignment` and `Project`.

Comment: You have `User` instead of `Programmer` there. I take that you have used that in the form, right?

Answer (score 1):

ref [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002278)

```
check_box does not work when the check box goes within an array-like parameter
```

Following should work for you

```
<% @programmers.each do |programmer| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "project[programmer]", programmer.email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: or i think you have to use array of checkboxes `project[programmer][]`

Comment: how do I update the project_id and corresponding programmer_id to assignments table?